# Node, Webpack: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am using webpack and trying to add one quill addon but I am getting error.

```
ERROR in ./core/functions/frontCore.js 39:26
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (39:26)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * @param {File} file
|  */
> function saveToServer(file: File) {
|   const fd = new FormData();
|   fd.append('image', file);
```

My webpack config is simple :

```
module.exports = {


    // Entry point
    entry: './core/functions/frontCore.js',

    // Output
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/dist',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    mode: 'development'
};
```

Don't know why I am getting error. Firstly I was getting error in visual studio code with function `saveToServer(file: File)` that it need to be ts file but it was solved by an article here on SO. But I can't go through this don't know what is problem.

Comment: That is typescript syntax, so you're going to have to use the ts-loader https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/

Comment: @PatrickHund Thank you for you answer :)